# Ajax load div

Tags: jquery, html

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой! Имеется див, нужно сделать так что бы при нажатии на его происходил ajax запрос и подгружалась страница! Вот код дива

```
<div class="tweet_box" id="26"></div>
```

А вот код скрипта который должен получать значение id, и выполнять ajax запрос!

```
    <script>

$('.tweet_box').live("click",function() 
{
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
 var handler = "poster.php?id="+ID;

$.ajax({ url:handler, cache: false, success:function(html){
$(".span8").html(html);
}
return false;
});
});

</script>
```

Подскажите как это можно реализовать по другому или в чем может быть моя ошибка ? При нажатии на новость не происходит считывание id и загрузка ajax'ом полной статьи!Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Забыть про метод **.live()**, а использовать **.on()**.

P.S. Ну, почему не следить за изменениями на официальном сайте, а использовать "дедушкины" уроки?

Comment: @Deonis дедушкины **видео**уроки. вот почему :) а ещё бумажные книжки типа jQuery за 48 часов (написанные во времена 1.3)